# Dependency management using Conan with a CMake project under VS2017

Tags: c++, cmake, visual-studio-2017, conan

I'm trying to setup a development environment for C++ to compile under Linux x64 using CMake integration with VS2017. To better manage dependencies I choose to use Conan but I'm pretty new to this software and I'm wondering what's the best way to have VS2017 to recognize the dependencies of the project.

For example, I've used Conan to install the POCO library for C++ but when I open the Main.cpp file it doesn't recognise the header files location and I'm not really sure where to add those paths.

[image]

Can anyone give some hints to solve this?

If needed all the source files are in my Github repo [CppLinuxVS](https://github.com/lusocoding/CppLinuxVS).

**UPDATE**

As per comments on this post, below you can find the contents of the files:

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
project(CppLinuxVS)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)
add_definitions("-std=c++11")

# Download automatically, you can also just copy the conan.cmake file
if(NOT EXISTS "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conan.cmake")
   message(STATUS "Downloading conan.cmake from https://github.com/conan-io/cmake-conan")
   file(DOWNLOAD "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/conan-io/cmake-conan/v0.8/conan.cmake"
                 "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conan.cmake")
endif()

include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conan.cmake)
conan_cmake_run(CONANFILE conanfile.txt
                BASIC_SETUP CMAKE_TARGETS
                BUILD missing)

add_executable(CppLinuxVS Main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(CppLinuxVS ${CONAN_LIST})
```

**conanfile.txt**

```
[requires]
Poco/1.8.0@pocoproject/stable

[generators]
cmake
```

**UPDATE 2**

Output of CMake inside VS2017 after downloading the conan.cmake file into the project instead of having the download specified in CMakeLists.txt. Also updated the CMakeLists.txt to require CMake 3.1.2 as per suggestion in the comments.

```
1> 17:52:57: Copying files to remote machine...
1> 17:53:00: Finished copying files (elapsed time 00h:00m:02s:799ms).
1> /usr/local/bin/cmake -G "Unix Makefiles"  -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Debug" "\var\tmp\src\03967bd6-44be-4e31-b449-a34a45d7109d\Linux-Debug"
1> -- Conan ** WARNING** : This detection of settings from cmake is experimental and incomplete. Please check 'conan.cmake' and contribute
1> -- Conan executing: conan install /var/tmp/src/03967bd6-44be-4e31-b449-a34a45d7109d/Linux-Debug/conanfile.txt -g cmake -s build_type=Debug -s os=Linux -s compiler=gcc -s compiler.version=5 -s compiler.libcxx=libstdc++11 --build=missing
1> PROJECT: Installing /var/tmp/src/03967bd6-44be-4e31-b449-a34a45d7109d/Linux-Debug/conanfile.txt
1> Requirements
1>     OpenSSL/1.0.2l@conan/stable from 'conan-center'
1>     Poco/1.8.0@pocoproject/stable from 'conan-center'
1>     zlib/1.2.11@conan/stable from 'conan-center'
1> Packages
1>     OpenSSL/1.0.2l@conan/stable:f68b4e006611addfaec53a2f3d5c0e6b0406266d
1>     Poco/1.8.0@pocoproject/stable:e3d8f1070a587658375103e87fd35c8b5c372b6e
1>     zlib/1.2.11@conan/stable:15c6f8a55cbf8b39b86ca055629a91be1b2d3cf5
1> 
1> zlib/1.2.11@conan/stable: Already installed!
1> OpenSSL/1.0.2l@conan/stable: Already installed!
1> Poco/1.8.0@pocoproject/stable: Already installed!
1> PROJECT: Generator cmake created conanbuildinfo.cmake
1> PROJECT: Generator txt created conanbuildinfo.txt
1> PROJECT: Generated conaninfo.txt
1> -- Conan: Loading conanbuildinfo.cmake
1> -- Current conanbuildinfo.cmake directory: /var/tmp/build/03967bd6-44be-4e31-b449-a34a45d7109d/build/Linux-Debug
1> -- Conan: Compiler GCC>=5, checking major version 5
1> -- Conan: Checking correct version: 5
1> -- Conan: Using cmake targets configuration
1> -- Library PocoUtild found /root/.conan/data/Poco/1.8.0/pocoproject/stable/package/e3d8f1070a587658375103e87fd35c8b5c372b6e/lib/libPocoUtild.a
1> -- Library PocoMongoDBd found /root/.conan/data/Poco/1.8.0/pocoproject/stable/package/e3d8f1070a587658375103e87fd35c8b5c372b6e/lib/libPocoMongoDBd.a
1> -- Library PocoNetd found /root/.conan/data/Poco/1.8.0/pocoproject/stable/package/e3d8f1070a587658375103e87fd35c8b5c372b6e/lib/libPocoNetd.a
1> -- Library PocoNetSSLd found /root/.conan/data/Poco/1.8.0/pocoproject/stable/package/e3d8f1070a587658375103e87fd35c8b5c372b6e/lib/libPocoNetSSLd.a
1> -- Library PocoCryptod found /root/.conan/data/Poco/1.8.0/pocoproject/stable/package/e3d8f1070a587658375103e87fd35c8b5c372b6e/lib/libPocoCryptod.a
1> -- Library PocoDatad found /root/.conan/data/Poco/1.8.0/pocoproject/stable/package/e3d8f1070a587658375103e87fd35c8b5c372b6e/lib/libPocoDatad.a
1> -- Library PocoDataSQLited found /root/.conan/data/Poco/1.8.0/pocoproject/stable/package/e3d8f1070a587658375103e87fd35c8b5c372b6e/lib/libPocoDataSQLited.a
1> -- Library PocoZipd found /root/.conan/data/Poco/1.8.0/pocoproject/stable/package/e3d8f1070a587658375103e87fd35c8b5c372b6e/lib/libPocoZipd.a
1> -- Library PocoXMLd found /root/.conan/data/Poco/1.8.0/pocoproject/stable/package/e3d8f1070a587658375103e87fd35c8b5c372b6e/lib/libPocoXMLd.a
1> -- Library PocoJSONd found /root/.conan/data/Poco/1.8.0/pocoproject/stable/package/e3d8f1070a587658375103e87fd35c8b5c372b6e/lib/libPocoJSONd.a
1> -- Library PocoFoundationd found /root/.conan/data/Poco/1.8.0/pocoproject/stable/package/e3d8f1070a587658375103e87fd35c8b5c372b6e/lib/libPocoFoundationd.a
1> -- Library pthread not found in package, might be system one
1> -- Library dl not found in package, might be system one
1> -- Library rt not found in package, might be system one
1> -- Library ssl found /root/.conan/data/OpenSSL/1.0.2l/conan/stable/package/f68b4e006611addfaec53a2f3d5c0e6b0406266d/lib/libssl.a
1> -- Library crypto found /root/.conan/data/OpenSSL/1.0.2l/conan/stable/package/f68b4e006611addfaec53a2f3d5c0e6b0406266d/lib/libcrypto.a
1> -- Library dl not found in package, might be system one
1> -- Library z found /root/.conan/data/zlib/1.2.11/conan/stable/package/15c6f8a55cbf8b39b86ca055629a91be1b2d3cf5/lib/libz.a
1> -- Conan: Adjusting default RPATHs Conan policies
1> -- Conan: Adjusting language standard
1> -- Configuring done
1> -- Generating done
1> -- Build files have been written to: /var/tmp/build/03967bd6-44be-4e31-b449-a34a45d7109d/build/Linux-Debug
1> Starting CMake target info extraction ...
1> Extracted source files and headers.
1> Extracted global settings.
1> Extracted code model.
1> Collating data ...
1> Target info extraction done.
```

**CMakeLists.txt updated**

```
project(CppLinuxVS)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1.2)
add_definitions("-std=c++11")

include(conan.cmake)
conan_cmake_run(CONANFILE conanfile.txt
                BASIC_SETUP CMAKE_TARGETS
                BUILD missing)

add_executable(CppLinuxVS Main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(CppLinuxVS ${CONAN_LIBS})
```

Comment: According to Stack Overflow rules, the code should be in the question post, not linked. While content of [conan.cmake](https://github.com/conan-io/cmake-conan/blob/develop/conan.cmake) can be treated as well-known, content of your `CMakeLists.txt` is not, so it should be added into the question post.

Comment: It is important also that you specify the steps you followed. Likely you did a ``conan install`` method to get the dependencies, but where? With which settings? The CMakeLists.txt will be looking for the generated ``conanbuildinfo.cmake`` generally in the ``${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}``  folder, but with the CMake integration, VS puts the binary-dir folder elsewhere. I'll suggest printing ``${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}`` in the CMakeLists.txt, then moving to that folder to execute the ``conan install``. Also, consider submitting issues to github: https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues.

Comment: Since you are calling conan_cmake_run with the flag CMAKE_TARGETS
You might try to use target_link_libraries(CppLinuxVS CONAN_PKG::Poco) 
instead of target_link_libraries(CppLinuxVS ${CONAN_LIBS}) (Be careful you used ${CONAN_LIST}

Comment: Additionally, you can't use CMake Targets  with CMake < 3.1.2 so you might change your minimum required by 3.1.2 or use ${CONAN_LIBS} without CMAKE_TARGETS flags . I can provide you a complete answer if you like.

Comment: Any chance you solved it? I'm Facing same problem

Answer (score 1):

@lusocoding here is a project i setup to demonstrate a working combination of VS -> Cmake -> Conan.

https://github.com/solvingj/vs-cmake-conan-demo

One of the critical parts (as I recall) was CMakeSettings.json, which is supposed to be a machine-specific setting that you don't typically commit to git. However, at the time, there were customizations (i think it was the CLI flags passed to CMake) which i had to add to to make it work. So, i committed that file to git for the demonstration.

See if you can clone and use the project as is, and then slowly compare with your project to find differences.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the tips @solvingJ I was able to clone your repo and verified that it works fine, but your setup is for Windows builds and not Linux, as I was trying to do. It seems the issues I'm having are related to that because, as soon as I changed the compilation to target Linux, even your repo stopped working. But thanks the same. Your repo has a lot of useful info.