# Using Visual Studio remote debug and conan together

Tags: visual-studio, centos, remote-debugging, rsync, conan

My setup is as so:

1. Windows PC running VS 2017 with remote debugger
2. Centos machine running rsync and not connected to conan server
3. Conan server with packages for Windows and Centos

When I compile and run my C++ code on Windows, I can pull the Windows packages from Conan and use them.

I would like to use a similar method for running with the vs remote debugger.

When I run my cmake with conan.cmake to pull the conan packages it always think I am running on windows, and does not transfer the packages to the centos

I found a similar question here: [related question](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49150146/dependency-management-using-conan-with-a-cmake-project-under-vs2017&ved=2ahUKEwj-5_DDldnpAhWE_qQKHZ42BOMQrAIoAjAAegQIBxAJ&usg=AOvVaw1Ms0aQ4tqwkf_ohdTZQbO6&cshid=1590759395539)

Comment: You need to define the input settings and options, like ``-s os=Linux -s compiler=gcc ....``. It is completely recommended to use ``profile`` files, that define your different configurations. It seems you might be relying on the ``conan.cmake`` wrapper? We would need more details about your setup.

Comment: Indeed I am using the conan.cmake. are the input settings and options you are refring to comes from conan? Also, I am using profile file for diffrent options of visual studio (32/64 debug/release). But thats not helpping me with the conan packages as they are on the windows and not copied to the centos

Comment: Is there a way maybe to make conan copy the packages to the centos using the conan.cmake?

Comment: It is very likely that the ``conan.cmake`` is not prepared for cross-building, because it uses mostly cmake auto-detection, but it will probably get settings from the build system, not for the host one. I would recommend to make this scenario work first without ``conan.cmake`` and then automating it with ``conan.cmake`` if you want. At the end of the day, all ``conan.cmake`` does is call ``conan install``. Now with the new cross-build model (https://blog.conan.io/2020/05/07/New-conan-release-1-25.html) you might have way more control with ``conan install``